# Using a Button remove item from sortable list

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable div containers, that each contain a button to delete itself. This button calls a function which removes the div container from the DOM. Everything looks fine, until I begin to drag and re-order the sortable items. Now the deleted element does not show in the GUI (which is expected), however doing a check of the sortable array, seems to suggest it's still there.

How can I get it so that this array is properly updated during the removal? or during the sorting. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is my javascript.

```
$(function() {

    // Make Cron Jobs Sortable
    $("#controlContainer").sortable({
            items: "> div:not(#controlHeader), serialize",
            create: function(event, ui) {
                    cronJobOrder = $(this).sortable("toArray",{attribute: "id"});
            },
            update: function(event, ui) {
                    cronJobOrder = $(this).sortable("toArray",{attribute: "id"});
            }
    });

});
```

Then my function

```
// the variable being passed in is the "Delete" button reference, that way it can find the div container it's in.
function deleteCronJob(cronJob) {

    var confirmation = window.confirm("Are You Sure?");

    if (confirmation) {
            $(cronJob).parents(".cronJobElement:eq(0)").fadeOut("medium", function() {
                    // Remove Item from cronJobOrder array
                    cronJobOrder.splice(cronJobOrder.indexOf($(this).attr("id")),1);
                    // Remove CronJob from View
                    $(this).attr("id").remove();
            });
    } else {
            return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I set up for you a simple fiddle. Alerting the sortable elements as array (and the updates after the remove button is clicked). Build your stuff around it.

http://jsfiddle.net/K3Kxg/

```
function sortableArrayAlert() {
    sortableArray = $('li').toArray();
    alert(sortableArray);
}

$(function(){
    sortableArrayAlert();
    $('ul').sortable();
    $('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().remove().then(sortableArrayAlert());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks ggzone. This was super helpful, I didn't think of using a function to do the sorting and just calling that everytime things get changed.